# DLang - Template constraints - type must implement interface

Tags: templates, constraints, d

I'm trying to convert the following C# code in to D, however I can't figure out how to make the template constraints work.

**C# Implementation**

```
public interface IComponent
{

} 

public class Container
{
    public T CreateComponent<T>() where T: IComponent, new()
    {
        // Trivial initialisation for example
        var t = new T(); 
        return t;
    }
}
```

**D Implementaiton**

```
public interface Component
{

}

public class Container
{
    public T createComponent(T)()
    {
        // Trivial initialisation for example
        auto t = new T();
        return t;
    }
}
```

How can I re-create the "where T: IComponent" constraint?

I've tried various expressions combining is, typeof etc. but can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if all you're trying to do is require that `T` implement the interface `IComponent`, then `is(T : IComponent)` will test that `T` is implicitly convertible to `IComponent` (which is the case when `IComponent` is a base class of `T` or an interface that it implements). So, you'd end up with something like

```
public class Container
{
    public T createComponent(T)()
        if(is(T : IComponent))
    {
        // Trivial initialisation for example
        auto t = new T();
        return t;
    }
}
```

Now, technically, other stuff can match if `alias this` is used to define an implicit conversion, which isn't likely to be common, but if you're being more paranoid about it, you could make the constraint also check that `T` is class - `is(T == class)`.

```
public class Container
{
    public T createComponent(T)()
        if(is(T == class) && is(T : IComponent))
    {
        // Trivial initialisation for example
        auto t = new T();
        return t;
    }
}
```

Then, `T` must be a class, and it must implicitly convert to `IComponent`. However, it *is* still technically possible for `T` to be a class which doesn't implement `IComponent` but does define an `alias this` which converts to an `IComponent` (it's just no longer possible for `T` to be a struct which does that). So, it's not perfect, but I don't know of a way to ensure that an implicit conversion is done via inheritance rather than `alias this`. So, unfortunately, I don't know of a way to absolutely guarantee that `T` is a class which implements `IComponent`. The most that I know how to do is to ensure that it implicitly converts to an `IComponent, which *almost* always means that it implements it.

However, the reality of the matter is that in the vast majority of cases, simply checking `is(T : IComponent)` is plenty, and depending on how your code is written, it might even work with a type which implicitly converts to `IComponent` but isn't actually an `IComponent`. So, the fact that `alias this` throws a spanner in the works may not actually be a problem. However, in general, `alias this` is a bane of generic code and why most generic code shouldn't be checking for implicit conversions. It's far too easy for a type to implicitly convert via `alias this` but not actually be converted in the function, in which case, it either won't compile, or it could have strange behavior if it supports the same operations that the target type does but those operations don't have the same results as they would if the original type were actually converted to the target type. So, if you actually *want* implicit conversions in templated code, you should force the implicit conversion by assigning the argument to the target type. But since you're looking to test for an interface rather than implicit conversions in general, what you probably want is a test which tests for that without allowing implicit conversions via `alias this`. Unfortunately, the only way that I know of to check at compile time whether one type derives from another or implements a specific interface is to check whether it implicitly converts to that base class or interface.

But maybe there's some fun voodoo with traits that's actually able to do it. If there is, we should probably add something to std.traits which does that for you, and if there isn't, maybe we should find a way to add it, since `alias this` can definitely be annoying if you don't want it. But fortunately, it's not a problem that comes up in most code, and if you're not writing a public API, then you only have to worry about it if you're declaring types with `alias this`. If you're not, then it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a template constraint, just a template specialization:

```
T createComponent(T : IComponent)() { /* some code */ }
```

Comment: Actually, it _does_ match structs and classes which have an `alias this` which converts to an `IComponent` (I just tried it to make sure). So, it really isn't any different from using a template constraint in this case. It's just slightly shorter. Personally, I tend to forget that template specializations like this exist in D, because template constraints are far more powerful, and you often need that extra power. So, template specializations frequently don't work, and they're a redundant feature (but template specializations came first, which is why we have both).

Comment: When I saw this question, this answer first came to my mind. I like template constraints, but I humbly believe they make code less readable then simple template specialisations.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis I tried `createComponent!SomeStructWithAliasThis` and it didn't compile for me. I'll try and get an example soon.

Comment: @DejanLekic Perhaps, but they only work in very simply cases. In particular, they won't work with anything involving ranges, so inevitably, you end up having to use template constraints anyway in most cases, and after using them that much, they really don't seem ugly to me anymore. And unfortunately, template specializations have slightly different semantics than template constraints do even for the same thing (`:` doesn't quite mean implicit conversion for template specializations), and I'm likely to have to look up and/or test template specializations to know quite what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

In typical fashion I found the answer moments after asking here http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/is_expr.html

```
public T addComponent(T)()
    if (is(T: Component))
```